# How Do I Get GMT+01:00 with php

Tags: php, date, time, timezone, gmt

Please I have search through stackoverflow and couldn't find the right answer to this. I want to output a date for my country Nigeria on a website.

Nigeria timezone is GMT+01:00

I have this

```
    <?php
         date_default_timezone_set("WAT");

         echo date("M d, Y h:i a")."<p></p>";
         //echo time();
    ?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [addition of gmt times in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763459/addition-of-gmt-times-in-php)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you got the timezone wrong.
According to this [list](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.africa.php) it is `Africa/Lagos`

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Africa/Lagos");

echo "<p>" . date("M d, Y h:i a") . "</p>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks it really worked, and the document is very informative.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set below timezone based on recommended TIMEZONE only

date_default_timezone_set("Africa/Lagos");

More details on Your country based timezone you can find on below link

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.africa.php

In General For continent on the earth wise bifurcation you can refer below link

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php